# How to Set On click Listener On the Custom List view in android

Tags: android

I am trying to set On Click Listener on the List view. I have used the View holder and Base Adapter for Inflating the List view . I have used following Code:: Myonclicklistneer

```
myonclicklistneer = new Myonclicklistneer();
listView.setOnItemClickListener(myonclicklistneer); 

//Listneer Is 
class Myonclicklistneer implements OnItemClickListener
    {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long arg3) {
            Log.i("MyLog", "DONE DONE Listneer Is set!!!");

        }

    }
```

What is my problem that Listneer is setting and I am Inflating 3 Text View and 1 EditText.Whenever I click on any of the widgets in the row Listener has to be set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `android:focusable="false"` to other view of the ListView to make ListView Clickable.

Comment: Thanks Lalit It's working properly... for the Text view But for the Edit text It is not working. On the Edit text I have set the Textwatcher separately.                                EditTextWacher editTextWacher = new EditTextWacher(viewHolder);
  viewHolder.editTextQuantity.addTextChangedListener(editTextWacher); How to listener on the Edittext 90% Requirement is set now 10 % is pending It depends upon the Edittext...

Comment: @mayurrahatekar You should ask this as seprate question,Or update the main question.

Answer (score 4):

As I understand it, you have created your own custom `Adapter` by extending `BaseAdapter`.

Instead of setting an `OnItemClickListener` you should set an `OnClickListener` on each view inside the `getView()`-method of your `Adapter`.

Add the `OnClickListener` to your `Adapter`-class as an inner class:

```
private class MyOnClickListener implements OnClickListener
{
  @Override
  public void onClick(View view) {
     //Do what needs to be done.
  }
}
```

Then inside your `getView()`-method:

```
public View getView() {
   //Inflate the view and get references to your TextViews/EditText.
   TextView text = (TextView) view.findViewById( R.id.myListItemTextView );

   //Set the onClickListener for each of the TextViews/EditTexts.
   text.setOnClickListener( new MyOnClickListener() );
}
```