# setOnClickListener on child elements in ListView?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

I am trying to attach an OnClickListener on the child elements in a custom list view.The class that I am using extends ListActivity. In my custom list view I have two text views and a button. I need to attach an OnClickListener on each of them. The following is my code.

```
final ListView listview = getListView();
          listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {



            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                    long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                callBut= (Button)listview.getChildAt(position);
                callBut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Log.d("Call Phone","");
                    }

                });
            }
```

But when I click on the child element Nothing is shown on the log.

Comment: You should set `onClickListener` in adapter inside.

Comment: use custom Adapter for adding `OnClickListener` to each row views in ListView instead of in `onItemClick` because this will add click listener to view when ListView row pressed

Comment: If you are using `ListActivity`, you should override `protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)` instead of creating item click listener instance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Set On click Listener On the Custom List view in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8486511/how-to-set-on-click-listener-on-the-custom-list-view-in-android)

Comment: I added the method inside getView in my adapter and it worked .....
thanks @deathember
post it as answer

Comment: Please let us know how you are bind this items to list please set array adapter class

Answer (score 0):

You can atach a OnItemClickListener

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
callBut= (Button)listview.getChildAt(position);
```

to

```
callBut= (Button)findViewById(R.id.yourCallButton);
```

Comment: It is not working.The layout I am using is a custom one